# Spark WriteAheadLog timeout making Spark stream inactive

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Spark streaming (DStream) for streaming the data and processing it. My stream fetches data from MQ and process it with checkpointing enabled and writing checkpoint to S3. It was all working fine till one day we saw this on Prod.

Our stream stopped processing MQ messages (can see in logs 0 message processed when messages got piled up at MQ) after it encountered this exception.

I could not find much documentation on it if this is the expected behavior. I can increase the timeout on this property "spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.batchingTimeout" but is it worth it ?

Any recommendations?

```
           WARN scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker: Exception thrown while writing record: BatchAllocationEvent(1631149500000 ms,AllocatedBlocks(Map(0 -> ArrayBuffer()))) to the WriteAheadLog.
           java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [15000 milliseconds]
               at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
               at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
               at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.BatchedWriteAheadLog.write(BatchedWriteAheadLog.scala:84)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.writeToLog(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:242)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.allocateBlocksToBatch(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:122)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.allocateBlocksToBatch(ReceiverTracker.scala:209)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:248)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
               at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
               at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
           
           WARN scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker: Exception thrown while writing record: BlockAdditionEvent(ReceivedBlockInfo(0,Some(1),None,WriteAheadLogBasedStoreResult(input-0-1631091366845,Some(1),FileBasedWriteAheadLogSegment(s3a://something-prod/somethingPROD/something_CHECKPOINT/something/receivedData/0/log-1631149526801-1631149586801,0,6504)))) to the WriteAheadLog.
           java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [15000 milliseconds]
               at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
               at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
               at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:220)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.BatchedWriteAheadLog.write(BatchedWriteAheadLog.scala:84)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.writeToLog(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:242)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker.addBlock(ReceivedBlockTracker.scala:89)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$ReceiverTracker$$addBlock(ReceiverTracker.scala:347)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ReceiverTracker.scala:522)
               at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1$$anon$1.run(ReceiverTracker.scala:520)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
           WARN scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Error reported by receiver for stream 0: Error in block pushing thread - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to add block to receiver tracker.
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushAndReportBlock(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:163)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushArrayBuffer(ReceiverSupervisorImpl.scala:129)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver.store(Receiver.scala:124)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.jms.AsynchronousJmsReceiver$AsyncGeneratedBlockHandler.onPushBlock(AsynchronousJmsReceiver.scala:69)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator.pushBlock(BlockGenerator.scala:297)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$receiver$BlockGenerator$$keepPushingBlocks(BlockGenerator.scala:269)
               at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.BlockGenerator$$anon$1.run(BlockGenerator.scala:110)
```